# Does Adding a Rack in Cassandra necessitate a cluster rebalance? (non-vnode)

Tags: cassandra

If you use rack designations and add new racks to a current cluster do you have to rebalance everything out after?

For example we currently have 2 racks. Then we'll double the node count by adding two new racks. Will cassandra have to rebalance the replica's out. The primary tokens will be balanced because the new nodes will have the correct tokens. But the replica's seem like they would be interspersed incorrectly.

If we know we'll be adding racks in the future, but we cannot afford to rebalance the cluster, should we just avoid racks completely in the first place?

Cassandra version is 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after working with Cassandra for longer. Short answer is yes. Due to how Cassandra saves data if the nodes are not perfectly balanced across racks and in the right order you'd either have to rebalance or physically move the hardware to balance the racks. It seems like it is better to just manually balance the cluster by having the token's alternate racks than using cassandra's internal rack designation. However with vnodes this becomes less of an issue I believe.